# Override FragmentGridPagerAdapter's getFragmentMethod, supply custom fragment not work

Tags: android, wear-os

I am working on GridViewPager of Android Wear.  Trying to provide custom UI to my cards.
When extending FragmentGridPagerAdapter, I override the getFragment method.

If using CardFragment (from sample code), no problem.  However, if I use BlankCardFragment(where custom UI is), it complains with the compile time error: **Type mismatch: cannot convert from BlankCardFragment to Fragment**
Both CardFragment and BlankCardFragment extend Fragment, why the latter one fails.

```
@Override
public Fragment getFragment(int row, int col) {
    Page page = PAGES[row][col];
    String title = page.titleRes != 0 ? mContext.getString(page.titleRes) : null;
    String text = page.textRes != 0 ? mContext.getString(page.textRes) : null;
    CardFragment fragment = CardFragment.create(title, text, page.iconRes);

    //BlankCardFragment fragment;
    //fragment = new BlankCardFragment();
    return fragment;
}
```

Here is the BlankCardFragment.java

```
public class BlankCardFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card_blank,
            container, false);

    return v;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you extending the right kind of `Fragment` ([support version](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html) vs [regular version](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)) in `BlankCardFragment`?

Comment: @Kei your earlier comment was removed for being too chatty. In general, site policy is to thank users for their (useful) answers by accepting them (which you already did) and/or upvoting them. Just FYI!